# Problem with deleting in a Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am having trouble with the cascade types, I have 3 tables. 2 made by me and the join table is generated through hibernate. 
Here are my tables:

activity

appointment

appointment_activity

My problem is that when I try to delete an appointment or an activity, it does not let me. The column in the join table appointment_activity is also there. I know I should not have Remove in many to many relationships, so I don't know what to do to fix the problem.

here is my appointment class:

```
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "appointment_activity",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "activity_id")}
    )
    private Set<Activity> activities;
```

My activity class:

```
public class Activity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "activities",
            cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Set<Appointment> appointments;
```

Comment: You have to delete all the appointment activity rows that point to the particular appointment or activity you want to delete first, then you can delete the appointment or activity.

Comment: How do I delete the the appointment activity row first in postman? What is the logic

Comment: You cant do it just from postman, you have to write the proper code. For example, if you want to delete an appointment, first you have to remove all foreign keys point to it from the appointment_activity table, then delete the appointment itself. You can delete it by sql/jpql, or select all activities which contain that appointment and remove it from the activity's set and save back all, this will delete the connection. After that simply delete the appointment.

Comment: Can you guys give me some reference, what should I google search?